# I want to log encrypted User ID while logging

Tags: java

I am logging userID in my project with the getXxx() method. `logger.info("printing user id"+user.getUserId());`
Now for the security purpose I can't log the userId as plain text, I need to encrypt this. At the same time I can't change logic in getXxx() method, as I am using this as part of my business logic. I want, only when I logging in then only user id got encrypt.

How can I do that?

Comment: For a starter you may want to tell us what encryption method you want to use. At which point you just encrypt the result of `getUserId()` and pass the encrypted string to `logger.info()`

Comment: Do you want to be able to recover the name it or do you just want to hide it?

Comment: Depends on how you want to encrypt. I would say the largest choice will be if you want symmetric or asymmetric encryption. Probably easier to go with asymmetric from a security point view (i.e. if you know the userId you can get the encrypted id, but not the other way around). In terms of how you would use it; I would probably add a helper function `encrpytUserId(user.getUserId())` or add it directly to the user class `user.getEncryptedUserId()`

Answer (score 1):

I would argue the fact that you can't log userIds, in theory this does not expose any user personal information, the id is worthless without the link to the user personal data such as (name, lastname, phonenumber,...) in that sense should be find to have the userId there. if you definetly cant do it, you could potentially do something like:

1) print the traceId of the request so that you can correlate multiple lines of code with your use case, for this you can use the MDC context so that you dont need to do this every-time you log something.

2) wrap your getUserId with an encryption method defaultEncrypt(user.getUserId())

3) add another getter to your domain object to do something like user.getEncryptUserId() which does this underneath. if using kotlin you can just add an extension function to do something like String.encrypt() and then do user.getUserId().encrypt()

Comment: Many websites have a publicly available userId. Take SO for example, your userId is `6446034`. If an advisory has access to logs and can directly see this ID, then they can easily glean information about you. It's best practice, and I would argue good faith, that software will anonymize/mask any information that can directly identify a user, even when that ID is not being linked to sensitive data. It's not trivial to identify what truly is considered sensitive data, and the more data you link to the customer, the more surface area you leave open to potential adversaries.

Comment: numeric ids are really bad in terms of security because you can iterate over then and get access to most of the user, if you use UUID for external and internal purposes then you save yourself of the trouble, again in someone have access to userId they cant track that down unless you log as well userId -> Name, otherwise its just an internal Id.